# SDWebImage - Method for performing tasks when setImageWithURL completes loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdwebimage

Just like the title says.  Given:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];
```

What is the best way to perform tasks once the image is loaded (or pulled from the cache) and displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setImageWithURL API is a super convenience method but you need a little more control so I suggest loading the image yourself with (heavily inspired from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/README.md):

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];

if (cachedImage) {
    [imageView setImage:cachedImage];
    [self doMyOtherCustomStuff];
} else {
    [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
}
```

...

```
- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self doMyOtherCustomStuff];
}
```

good luck!

Comment: I wish I could mark both as solutions.  This actually answers my questions more completely.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to implement the `SDWebImageManagerDelegate` protocol.  There is an example in the `SDWebImage` documentation.

Another option is to use KVO and watch the `image` property on `imageView`.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the SDWebImageManagerDelegate in the scan of the documentation... however KVO seemed like the easier fix.